# Sync of contacts without internet

Tags: sync, internet

If mobiles internert is off and i saved any contact on google account,then where it is stored actually before getting sync?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the contacts database can vary between manufacturers. In vanilla Android I believe it is at `/data/data/android.providers.contacts/databases`.

Comment: It is `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases`.